# Laravel - Upload File to Database

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, bootstrapping

**These are what I have :**

Database table named `lamanInformasi`, which has field named `isi`.

**This is what I want :**

User can upload multiple document or image files, and the files will be stored to database. The file names will be saved to `isi` field, and the files itself will be saved to a folder named `propic`. User also can show the file they want on the website and download it.

**This is what I have done :**

I used bootstrap plugin to input file. I used this [source](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput). I just used files inside the `js` and `css` folder. This is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container kv-main">
        <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Upload Files</h1>
        </div>

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="file-5" class="file" type="file" multiple data-preview-file-type="any" data-upload-url="#">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
        $("#file-5").fileinput({
            uploadUrl: "{{ url('lamanInformasi') }}",
            uploadAsync: false,
            previewFileIcon: '<i class="fa fa-file"></i>',
            allowedPreviewTypes: 'image',
            previewFileIconSettings: {
                'doc': '<i class="fa fa-file-word-o text-primary"></i>',
                'xls': '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o text-success"></i>',
                'ppt': '<i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o text-danger"></i>',
                'jpg': '<i class="fa fa-file-photo-o text-warning"></i>',
                'pdf': '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o text-danger"></i>',
                'zip': '<i class="fa fa-file-archive-o text-muted"></i>',
                'htm': '<i class="fa fa-file-code-o text-info"></i>',
                'txt': '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o text-info"></i>',
                'mov': '<i class="fa fa-file-movie-o text-warning"></i>',
                'mp3': '<i class="fa fa-file-audio-o text-warning"></i>',
            },
            previewFileExtSettings: {
                'doc': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(doc|docx)$/i);
                },
                'xls': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(xls|xlsx)$/i);
                },
                'ppt': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(ppt|pptx)$/i);
                },
                'zip': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(zip|rar|tar|gzip|gz|7z)$/i);
                },
                'htm': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(php|js|css|htm|html)$/i);
                },
                'txt': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(txt|ini|md)$/i);
                },
                'mov': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(avi|mpg|mkv|mov|mp4|3gp|webm|wmv)$/i);
                },
                'mp3': function(ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(mp3|wav)$/i);
                },
            }
        });
</script>
```

**This is my question**

How to save the files to database? How to show the files on the website? How to make the files become downloadable? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the file input field a name like

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input id="file-5" name="image" class="file" type="file" multiple data-preview-file-type="any" data-upload-url="#">
        </div>
</form>
```

Then in your controller method you can access the uploaded file and get the various properties

```
**EDIT**
$destinationPath = storage_path().'/uploads/';
or
$destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/';

//storage_path will give the fully qualified path to the storage folder
//public_path will give the fully qualified path to the public folder
//uploads - is the folder name where you want to store the user uploaded files, could be any name you prefer.
**EDIT end**

// Retrieving An Uploaded File
$file = Input::file('image');

// Determining If A File Was Uploaded
if (Input::hasFile('image'))
{
    //
}

// Determining If An Uploaded File Is Valid
if (Input::file('image')->isValid())
{
    //
}

// Moving An Uploaded File
Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath);
Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); //$filename is the name by which you want to store the file - change the name if required by by app.

// Getting Requested file path
$path = Input::file('image')->getRealPath();

// Getting Original name of the file
//**Edit** - gives the original filename as on uploading user's system. **Edit end**
$name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

// Getting uploaded File extention
$extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

// Getting Size of the file
$size = Input::file('image')->getSize();

// Getting MIME Type of uploaded file
$mime = Input::file('image')->getMimeType();
```

You can then store the properties in your database either through a `Model` corresponding to the database table in your case `lamanInformasi` or using query builder directly to the database table with raw queries.

Have a look at laravel documentation:
[Database - query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database)
[Eloquent - model approach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

You can use [Laravel's filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem) to retrieve the files from a folder and prepare a list view for users to see the files available for download.

Then use can leverage [Laravel's Response Download](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-downloads) to provide the download functionality for the users.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, I don't need uploadUrl in the <script>? What are the values of `$destinationPath` and `$fileName`? What is the difference of `$fileName` and `$name`? Do I have to use `insert` method inside your `if` statement above? If yes, then maybe like this: `DB::table('lamanInformasi')->insert(['isi' => $name]));`. Sorry if I asked too many question, I am really confused

Comment: I don't suggest anything about the bootstrap file input plugin. The `$destinationPath` is the path to the folder where you want to store the uploaded files. `$filename` is the name by which you want to store the uploaded file. `$name` is the original file name as on uploading user's system - see **EDIT**s in my answer. Typically I would create a model `LamanInformasi` corresponding to the database table with atleast the - name,size, mime-type and original-name fields. In the controller method within the `if` I would get all properties corresponding to the fields and perform db insert here.

Comment: Let me know if you need a step by step tutorial kind of thing, I may not be able to do it immediately but can write up something and flip the link to you.

Comment: I think step by step tutorial will be better for me to understand

Comment: Okay, give me some time, will write up the steps and flip the link to you.

Comment: @GraceMichelle Excuse me for the delay, I am a bit tied up right now. However I have managed to get two link for tutorials which I think would help you understand the flow basics for uploading file with Laravel. If you still have any issues, you can reach me at donkarnash AT thinkstudeo DOT io. Here are the links 1. http://devartisans.com/articles/file-upload-storage-laravel-5  2. http://tutsnare.com/upload-files-in-laravel/

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have edited my code, but I still have some problems. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051378/laravel-5-2-upload-files-to-database). And, I can't access your thinkstudeo account (donkarnash@thinkstudeo.io)

Comment: I will have a look at the code on the link. However my email is working and I am receiving emails on it. What error are you getting while try to reach (donkarnash@thinkstudeo.io)?

Comment: Oh, I think it's a website URL, so I access it from chrome, not from my email. Please take a look at my link. I need help ;) Thanks