# Laravel 5.2 - Upload Files to Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

**These are what I have :**

Database table named `lamanInformasi`, which has these fields: `id`, `judul`, `isi`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

**This is what I want :**

User can upload multiple document or image files, and the files will be stored to database. The file names will be saved to `isi` field, and the files itself will be saved to a folder named `propic`. User also can show all the data from database on the website.

**These are my codes :**

*create.blade.php*

```
<form action="lamanInformasiController@index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*lamanInformasiController.php*

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $file = new file;
    if (Input::hasFile('image'))
    {
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/propic/';
        $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $file = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $name . "." . $extension);
    }
    $file -> isi = $request->get($file);
    $file -> save();

    $lamanInformasi = LamanInformasi::all();
    return view('upload.index', compact('lamanInformasi'));
}
```

*index.blade.php*

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border= "1px solid black">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Judul</td>
            <td>Isi</td>
            <td>Created At</td>
            <td>Updated At</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($$lamanInformasi as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->judul}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->isi}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->updated_at}}</td>
         </tr>
         @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**When I run it, I have this error :**

```
ErrorException in ParameterBag.php line 90:
array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer
```

I have this in `ParameterBag line 89-91`

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->parameters) ? $this->parameters[$key] : $default;
}
```

**These are my questions :**

How to fix that error? Did I make the code right to upload files? Because I have tried similar code, and it's not working. Thanks

Comment: The way array_key_exists handles null, float, boolean, and 'integer-representing string' keys is inconsistent in itself and, in the case of bool and float, with the way these are converted when used as array offset.

Comment: @FullStack Sorry, I don't understand. What should I do?

Comment: look at this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php#90687

Comment: @FullStack I still don't understand what's wrong with my ParameterBag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are  a couple of things which you need to take care of. Try the code as below

**LamanInformasiController.php** - controller names are generally capitalized

```
class LamanInformasiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var LamanInformasi - include the use statement above for the model.
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Inject (model)LamanInformasi while instantiating the controller.
     * @param LamanInformasi $model
     */
    public function __construct(LamanInformasi $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function index()
    { 
        $lamanInformasi = $this->model->all();
        return view('upload.index', compact('lamanInformasi'));
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (Input::hasFile('image'))
        {
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/propic/';
            $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = $name.'.'.$extension;

            //store the file in the $destinationPath
            $file = Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

            //save a corresponding record in the database
            $this->model->create(['isi'=> $fileName]);

            //return success message
        } 
        //return failure message
    }

}   //don't forget to include the use statement for Input or write \Input
```

Then in your **index.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border= "1px solid black">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Judul</td>
        <td>Isi</td>
        <td>Created At</td>
        <td>Updated At</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($lamanInformasi as $file)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$file->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->judul}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->isi}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->updated_at}}</td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
</tbody>
```

And your form action should be accordingly

```
<form action="/upload8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

This should work, haven't tested though. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: I made a mistake. I should have put the code inside `index` function in `LamanInformasiController` to `store` function, so I move it. It works fine, until I select a file and click Submit, I have this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: I have this in `routes.php` `Route::resource('/upload8','LamanInformasiController');`

Comment: If you are using `Route::resource` then you should follow the REST convention and handle the storing of uploaded file in the `store` method of your `LamanInformasiController` and change the form action

Comment: Can you give the right code? I don't know which part I have to change

Comment: The `form action` goes to wrong URL. I access the form with this URL: `http://localhost/wfpProject/public/upload8`. When I click submit, it brings me to this URL: `http://localhost/upload8`

Comment: Haven't you set up a virtual host on your apache(or nginx - webserver)? If not then routing has to be addressed differently. I wouldn't be able to help in that case, you may have to search for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130215/discussion-between-grace-michelle-and-donkarnash).